# How to change Options menu dots color for the theme "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

To change the default option menu icon color(3 vertical dote), i have tried adding

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

But it doesn't make any change. I think it is not working coz my AppTheme parent is Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. So can anybody help me on this?

Comment: add this to your style `<item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way of doing it is by adding

`<item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>`

or

`<item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>`

to your primary Theme in order to change it to light or dark.

EDIT: In order to add any color for the overflow icon you would have to override the `actionOverflowButtonStyle` like so:

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
  </style>

  <style name="OverFlow" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_overflow_icon</item>
  </style>
```

You can easily create your own overflow icon from websites like [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&source.clipart=res%2Fclipart%2Ficons%2Fnavigation_more_vert.svg&name=ic_action_navigation_more_vert&theme=custom&color=9c27b0%2C60)

Comment: can i do it without changing my base theme?

Comment: The cleanest way of doing it is through themes. The other way of doing it would be through Java. You can call ```toolbar.setOverflowIcon(getDrawable()));``` in your `Toolbar` in order to update the color directly. Keep in mind that if you do that you would have to do it everysingle time for all your activities

Comment: but i need to add a custom color it may not be light or dark

Comment: but again here we are changing the src icon. Actually i need to change the color of the icon dots instead of changing the icon.

Comment: As far as I know the overflow icon is included in the default themes, I can't remember seeing any sort of mechanism to 'tint' the overflow menu by providing a color

Comment: Ok. Then i ll replace it with another icon. Can u help me on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191825/android-how-to-add-a-click-listener-to-menu-icon3-dots-at-the-top

Comment: As long as you mark this the answer to your question, I can have a look.

Comment: i got an answer for that anyway :)

Comment: @AlexStyl what about prelollipop? it does not work with kitkat although it was working with lollipop and higher.

Comment: If you don't want to mess up with pictures every time, you can replace "android:src" with "android:tint" and set a color (@color/white, etc)

Answer (score 5):

2019 - Easiest way to do is write the below code to your xml in toolbar code or where you want.

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

please give up vote if its work.

Answer (score 2):

You can Either use your own drawable or get the default overFlowIcon and change its *tint* value like below:

```
bd.toolbar.overflowIcon?.setTint(Color.WHITE)
```

To change the drawable all together, you just have to create your own vector and set it like below:

```
bd.toolbar.overflowIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_baseline_menu_24)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Toolbar, just add the following code in your Activity:

```
toolbar.setOverflowIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_more_vert_black_24dp));
```

By using this code, you can directly replace the "three dots" icon with any other icon of your choice. It worked for me.