# Android: How to add a click listener to menu icon(3 dots at the top)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

The onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method can be used to identify a click on each menu item. But i need to have a listener that can identify the click on the menu title (3 vertical dots at the top right of action bar). How could i implement one?

Comment: I think you may want to use `onCreateOptionsMenu` which should get called when you click the menu button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `onMenuOpened`([javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onMenuOpened(int,%20android.view.Menu))) on your activity.

Answer (score -1):

When you choose ***basic activity***, you get that 3 dot menu with it.

You don't have to add any click listener to that button it is created automatically. Try to run the app in emulator to see the results.

You can edit the default items of that menu from (res>menu>menu_main.xml)

Comment: I think he wants to do something else when the menu button is clicked. As is, this isn't really an answer

Comment: ok I yeah what is first thought was not needed but onCreateOptionMenu can't help .it can't be used to change the function of the menu button when clicked.